# override event render in full calendar

Tags: jquery, overriding, fullcalendar

I want to override the event render function in full calendar. My situation is like i have two js files and in one parent js i am creating a calendar and in the child js file i want to render events using child js file. so is there any way we can override event of full calendar from child js file.
here is my code eventRender function of Full calendar in parent js.

```
  eventRender: function(event, element) {
  $(element).children().addClass("fc-event-inner-"+event.statusId);
  $(element).children().attr("id",event.id);
  setEventColor(element, _statusIdToEventBackgroundColor[event.statusId],_statusIdToEventFontColor[event.statusId]);            
 createContextMenu(event.statusId);
 }
```

and this is code of child file

```
$(_panel).fullCalendar( 'renderEvent',loadedEvents, true);
```

this function from child file calls parent file's eventRender function. 
My calendar in parent Js file is like dummy. because i want all of my event's controlling and binding from child Js file. 
Is there any chance i can create or use the parent class's function(EventRender) in child js or any how i can access it by creating object.

Help appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can add your js function to the event render portion of the function. Please see the example [here](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) where they are adding the qTip plugin to the event.